# TeamCity compilation failure because of excluded files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, teamcity

I have a VS2010 solution with web-site project.

It has some excluded files.

When I build the solution with TeamCity,

compilation fails because it misses some files which are excluded.

TeamCity error:

> /BT.Account.csproj/Controls/Panels/TogglePanel.ascx(1, 0): error
>   ASPPARSE: Could not load type
>   'BT.Account.Controls.Panels.TogglePanel'.

Answer (score 0):

Do a fresh checkout to a new local directory and try to build that. Any error arising in TeamCity should be present in the new checkout. There you can see what really happens. My guess is that the .ascx file is still included in the project.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your TeamCity does when it runs a build.

*If* it runs an `aspnet_compiler.exe` job then you might get this error if your ASPX markup (not the codebehind) has an error in it.  I've seen this many times in some of my own TC projects :)

Normally ASPX markup errors are basically ignored until the page is visited (then resulting in a YSOD), but when you do an ASP.Net compile (or a publish) the markup will be compiled down into a DLL in the bin folder.  Hence any mistakes will cause a compilation error and make the build fail, with an error similar to yours.

If that's the case, have a look at TogglePanel.ascx and see if there are any errors.

If not, I hope you are able to solve the problem quickly and easily. Good luck :)